# How to get lastInsertId in phalcon ORM using oracle DB

Tags: php, database, oracle, orm, phalcon

I am using Phalcon as framework and Oracle as database. To manipulate data I am using Phalcon ORM. I am unable to retrieve the last inserted id after the save method. Below is my code for getting the last insert it.

```
if ($activityLog->save()) {
    echo "The robot id is", $activityLog->id, '<br>';
    echo "The robot id is", $activityLog->activity_id, '<br>';
} else {
    echo "Unable to create record";
}
```

The above code returns success message and every time one record is created in the database. But I am unable to retrieve the last inserted id.

I tried multiple methods but without luck. After studying I found that oracle didn't support auto increment field.

Comment: try `$id = $activityLog->lastInsertId();`

Comment: or `print $comande->id;` `id` must be the same name as your db field name.

Comment: $activityLog->lastInsertId(); and $comande->id; are not working !Mittul

Comment: `print_r($activityLog);` just after you save. and see what you get.